# How to use Git Extensions with BitBucket/Mercurial repository?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I a have repository on both github.com and bitbucket.org, and I am very familiar with using [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) for all repository functions on GitHub.  When I started using bitbucket.org repo's I have to use TortoiseHG for it, so I want to ask is there anyway I can use Git Extension for bitbucket repos?

Comment: You'll probably need something like [hg-git](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgGit) for that, but I can't see where it can fit in Git Extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/) backwards to use [Git locally to push to a Mercurial repository](http://traviscline.com/blog/2010/04/27/using-hg-git-to-work-in-git-and-push-to-hg/). Set up the Git repository, then Git Extensions should be able to use the repository normally.